# How do I set a default "Intro text" limit?

Tags: category-blog, readmore, intro-text

How do i set the default number of characters of INTRO TEXT before a "Read more" button is displayed on all my "Blogs" in Category Blog view.

Right now, all of the blogs show it's entire content which looks very long.

I have a menu item for "Category Blogs" and a few articles under the "Blog" category.

I am surprised this is a feature not built into Joomla. I do not want my users to need to manually insert a "Read more" button into their articles at different places.

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

At the time we don't have an automatic feature for this in the core, you can do this manually
 by adding one by one in your content or you can add a custom code via [override](https://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides) for the blog layout.

Also you can try with one extension in order to automate more this process, here you have
 two possible options:

- [Read Less - Text](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/news-display/article-elements/read-less-text)
- [BRTech Readmore](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/news-display/article-elements/brtech-readmore)

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you really need to use something like this - then you'll need to create JTableObserverContentLimiter for example. ([more info](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/joomla-dev-general/KWCTyD1Ga_8))
And check onBeforeSave if text has

`<hr class="readmore">`

or not. And if it doesn't - add it.

If you need detailed help with it - email me, kosarev@joomplace.com